# Android - where the user clicked on - find out the exact position

Tags: android, dictionary, user-controls, user-input

I'm working on a my new android application, It will show a `country map` to the user at first, then user can choose one of `Provinces` from the map. so the problem is how to find out the user's Selection؟

For ex: I show the map below and user choose `Napoli`, so how can I find out the user clicked on `Napoli`.

[image]

I can't find any thing on Google about this issue, can any body help me?

Comment: is this an activity or a surfaceview?

Comment: it is just an activity

Answer (score 0):

Use the onTouchEvent() method. You will receive MotionEvent event as a parameter, so what I would do is:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int x = Math.round(event.getX());
    int y = Math.round(event.getY());
    //x and y are the coordinates of the touched location

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //If the touch was a down press

        /* if the coordinates x and y fall within the imageView/Bitmap
           (not sure which you are using) then perform whatever action
           you want */
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: uhm that's right, you can get the position in this way. but how about drawing the map on the activity?